# Does this gutter look like it's installed correctly?

Tags: gutters

I've attached a photo showing that there are some gaps between the gutter and what it is attached to. The gaps aren't huge, but I can see the sky through them.  Are these gaps likely to cause problems or are they a non-issue?

[image: There are a couple of spots where I can see gaps.]

Comment: You aren't seeing the sky. You're seeing reflected light. Do the gutters work or don't they?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The roof and gutters were just replaced yesterday, so the gutters haven't really been used yet.  I was just going around the house to inspect it a bit when I noticed what appeared to me to be gaps in just a few spots.  There should be a rainstorm tomorrow, so I will know more then.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you understand how to use this site. You don't need to respond to answers with comments unless you need more information.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal for there to be some space so that things can dry. The edge of the roof should still dump water into the gutter.

You've picked the wrong sort of day to see if there's any functional problem. Come back in a rainstorm and see if it leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I just had the roof and gutters replaced, and when I went around the house to take a look at the gutters, I noticed these apparent gaps or spaces in just a few spots. If the light that I'm noticing is from the sky, I was worried that maybe the gutter isn't being covered by the edge of the roof at these spots. But maybe it is just reflected light from somewhere else, as someone commented. But based on how I was looking straight up to see this, it does seem more to me like I'm seeing light coming from above.

Comment: Since the roof is very high, I'm not sure whether I'll be able to get a view of how this gutter looks from above so I could check for some overhang from the roof edge.  But a storm is forecast for tomorrow, so I should be able to check if any water seems to be getting behind that gutter.